# Make a QDialog read only, but still with text selectable

Tags: c++, qt, selection, textselection, qdialog

Disclaimer: I'm not a Qt programmer, I'm just asking in case someone could solve an [issue about DB Browser for SQLite](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/issues/1123).

So, an [EditDialog widget](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/blob/master/src/EditDialog.h) is extending the [QDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html) class. As described in the issue, in some scenarios this widget is readonly, but it would be great if its text content could still be selectable.

There are two use cases:

- text selection with the mouse
- blinking caret, text selection with keyboard Shift + arrows

The [current solution](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/commit/fb6ea5ac60eceed8b777bd1334ed02210f71cddf) fixes only the first case. There is no blinking caret and keyboard selection doesn't work. Could this be improved?

Comment: Did you get an opportunity to test the answer I gave? I am a user of sqlitebrower myself, so I would be interested to know if my suggestion was helpful.

Comment: The developers haven't given news about it yet, but they are aware of this SO post, and the issue is tracked for the next DB4S release.

Comment: I just found this forum thread about this issue: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/39941-readonly-QTextEdit-with-visible-Cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the textarea is a `QTextEdit` or `QPlainTextEdit`, you should be able to fix this by adjusting the [text interaction flags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#textInteractionFlags-prop). Try something like this:

```
ui->editorText->setTextInteractionFlags(
    Qt.TextSelectableByMouse | Qt.TextSelectableByKeyboard)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just applied this to the DB Browser for SQLite and it works as expected.

Comment: Just a caveat, the caret doesn't blink. But apparently there is no better solution.